# Remove commas from numeric fields of a CSV file

Tags: perl

I have a input file like the following:

```
13/9/16,"71,150","49,122","13,212","3,135","3,652","140,271",0,Pull,301 Off,Standard,0,"6,237",43,53,0,"6,141","3,641","2,500","25,353","4,136","4,004",335,89,"1,909",312,382,49,183,0,"44,778"
14/9/16,"72,799","53,420","13,130","3,359","3,798","146,506",0,Pull,301 Off,Standard,0,"6,779",45,56,0,"6,678","4,178","2,500","25,940","4,232","3,979",349,96,"1,953",319,409,51,190,0,"46,525"
15/9/16,"97,532","16,861","12,386","6,066","17,323","150,168",F&F,+24,301 On,Standard,0,"2,413",203,102,0,"2,108","1,054","1,054","34,753","5,670","3,754","1,588",172,"2,616",427,739,231,867,0,"49,546"
```

I am trying to delete the commas `,` in strings that start and end with double-quote `"`.

So for example line 1 has the string `"71,150"` I would like that to look like `"71150"` with the rest of line 1 around it.

so the complete output for line 1 would look like the following:

```
13/9/16,"71150","49122","13212","3135","3652","140271",0,Pull,301 Off,Standard,0,"6237",43,53,0,"6141","3641","2500","25353","4136","4004",335,89,"1909",312,382,49,183,0,"44778"
```

I was thinking of something like

```
s/\,//g
```

but that will replace all of the commas in the entire file.

I know I can use the following line of code to find the strings that I want to change:

```
/\"[0-999]\,[0-999]\"/
```

but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Beware that `[0-999]` does _not_ mean "the numbers from 0 to 999". It means "a digit (only one!) in the range 0-9 or a 9 or a 9" which reduces to "a single digit from 0 to 9".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/("\d+),(\d+")/$1$2/g' infile.txt
```

- `"\d+` double quote followed by one or more digits
- `,` match a comma
- `\d+"` one or more digits followed by double quote
- `()` grouping used to capture matched pattern
- `$1` first captured group
- `$2` second captured group

If you want to change the file inplace, use

```
perl -i.bkp -pe 's/("\d+),(\d+")/$1$2/g' infile.txt
```

which will change `infile.txt` as well create a backup of original file as `infile.txt.bkp`

Comment: awesome thanks. Could you just explain what that does does perl evaluate the brackets first and also what does the \1 and \2 mean/do?

Comment: @glly: the `\1` and `\2` represent capture groups. The parens `()` in a Perl regex in this case captures. The left side one captures `"\d+`, the second one on the right captures `\d+"`, and they go into `\1` and `\2` respectively. The comma is outside of both capture groups, so it has to match, but it isn't captured. In the substitution side, the first and second capture groups are put back in, less the comma. So it's not really replacing the comma in this case, it's just capturing what its surrounded by and replacing the whole string with itself, less the comma

Comment: ahh that makes sense looking at it now, Thank you. Is always good to know.

Comment: Perl isn't sed. You should read [*Warning on `\1` Instead of `$1`*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-%5c1-Instead-of-%241)

Comment: You could be more exact in your digit matching groups by using `{1,3}` for the first and `{3}` for the second.

Comment: @Vogel612 True for the example lines shown here but that won't catch "1234,56". It depends on the actual input. A simple `\d+` will catch them all.

Comment: @PerlDog check the original post. I am rather sure OP only wants to match numbers smaller than 1000. (check for the incorrect character-class). Also removing the comma is only possible without data loss if you know how many places there are after the comma in the first place. This (and the fact that the example only contains 3 digits after the comma) leads me to believe that this fits OP's criteria better.

Answer (score 4):

If there is only ever a single comma in the numeric fields then you can use

```
perl -pe 's/"\d+\K,//g' input.txt
```

#### output

```
13/9/16,"71150","49122","13212","3135","3652","140271",0,Pull,301 Off,Standard,0,"6237",43,53,0,"6141","3641","2500","25353","4136","4004",335,89,"1909",312,382,49,183,0,"44778"
14/9/16,"72799","53420","13130","3359","3798","146506",0,Pull,301 Off,Standard,0,"6779",45,56,0,"6678","4178","2500","25940","4232","3979",349,96,"1953",319,409,51,190,0,"46525"
15/9/16,"97532","16861","12386","6066","17323","150168",F&F,+24,301 On,Standard,0,"2413",203,102,0,"2108","1054","1054","34753","5670","3754","1588",172,"2616",427,739,231,867,0,"49546"
```